# WSO2 Data Services Server - Adding a new Database support

Tags: mongodb, wso2, mongodb-java, wso2-data-services-server

How do I add new Database support (MongoDB) in 2.6.3 version of WSO2 Data Service Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DSS (2.6.3) with any database type if the database connectivity is exposed via JDBC. In other words, if your preferred database type exposes a JDBC driver/adapter for the users to connect to it via JDBC then you can use DSS to expose your data stored in your data store as a web service. Similarly, if MongoDB too has a JDBC adapter you wouldn't have any (or too many :) ) issues integrating that with DSS. However, there are some exceptions when it comes to exposing flat files such as google spreadsheeets, excel sheets, csv files as DSS uses the relevant client APIs such as Google gdate client API, Apache POI, etc to connect to those datasources and extract data. However, if we consider the general case is you need to have an adapter or a similar mechanism to connect to your datasource via JDBC.

But in the upcoming version of DSS (v3.0.0), it is planned to introduce custom datasource support so you can easily write an adapter to any datasource and use it with DSS.

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: Thanks Prabhath and Nuvio., I am going to try it out tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Adding a custom datasource support so that one can write adapters would be good feature. I am looking forward to it.

Comment: JDBC Driver that is available out there is not working as desired. Waiting for the new feature.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but I suppose that if is not supported by default you can always download the jar library for MongoDB and put it in `CARBON_HOME\repository\components\lib` and restart. For example for mysql I have the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar` in that folder.
Hope this help

Comment: Thanks Nuvio, I am going to try it out and post here on how it goes.